# BLAS routines in profiler?

Tags: fortran, blas, intel-mkl, gprof

I'm trying to profile some Fortran code that calls `GEMM` to do matrix multiplication.

I used to use double precision and was seeing `dgemm` calls as I would expect, but now that I've switched to single precision, I don't see `sgemm` at all anywhere in profiler.

To be honest, I don't understand how even `dgemm` appeared. Don't the BLAS libraries need to have been compiled with `-pg`to create the necessary symbols?

This is using intel MKL for the BLAS libraries and gprof for the profiler.

Comment: Where is your code? Do you ýse matmul()?

Comment: We really need a clear problem statement. Which profiler, in which configuration, does not see GEMM, in which code. Otherwise there are way too many variables we can only guess in your question.

Comment: I am directly calling `sgesvd` and directly calling `sgemm`, so not MATMUL.

Comment: I'm compiling my code with `-pg` and `-O3`. This produces a gmon.out file which I then use `gprof [EXECUTABLE_PATH]` to produce the profiler output.

Comment: Can you prepare a small [mcve] which just calls sgesvd or sgemm and which has this problem? Show us the problematic gprof output together with the code.

Answer (score 0):

First, I don't recommend *gprof*. Not only does it miss a lot, but it leads you into wrong thinking about performance, focussing on routines rather than on why the program is doing what it's doing.

I use random pausing. [*Here*](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/a/2719/1262) is a careful discussion about a problem similar to yours.
The thing about DGEMM is that it is about as fast as it can be, given that it is designed to be *flexible*, primarily, *not fast*.
So, for example, if your program spends a large fraction of its time multiplying small matrices, like 3x3, the DGEMM routine could actually spend 2/3 of its time checking its argument flags, and only 1/3 actually multiplying.
If you know that, then you can easily write your own ad-hoc multiplier, and get a massive speedup.
This is what randomly pausing and sampling the call stack will tell you.

Comment: I will also comment that the Intel compiler can generate inline code and/or call a specialized MKL routine when it recognizes matrix multiplication. I agree with Mike that if you are multiplying small matrices, don't use DGEMM and do use MATMUL.

Comment: Towards your point, Mike, I've ultimately switched to Intel VTune which is showing me the cost of SGEMM and all other MKL calls. (Big fan, Steve Lionel, big fan...)

Comment: @EMiller: I just looked at the [*source code of SGEMM*](http://www.netlib.org/lapack/explore-html/db/dc9/group__single__blas__level3_gafe51bacb54592ff5de056acabd83c260.html#gafe51bacb54592ff5de056acabd83c260). Lines 230 and 231 are calls to `lsame` that it does every time you call it. There are other calls as well. What I found was that, nearly all the time line 230 or 231 was on the stack. That meant that it was spending much more time checking its argument character flags than anything else. Eliminating that produced a huge speedup.

Comment: Is it the case that the Intel MKL uses the same source code?

Comment: @EMiller: No. The MATMUL routine doesn't have those options. We stayed away from MKL for worries about licenses.